# the area principle of biholomorphic mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f=\frac 1z +\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n $ is a biholomorphic mapping on $B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$,then prove that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n|a_n|^2\le1$$
I have known that when $D=B(0,R)\setminus\overline{B(0,r)},f:D\to G$ with f biholomorphic,the area of G is:
$$\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n|a_n|^2(R^{2n}-r^{2n})$$
and I thought it would be easy if only I should exchange r with 0,but that turned out to be not so easy.T_T

Comment: What does this have to do with holomorphic-bundles? Also, how about providing some context (what kind of techniques do you know, where does the problem come from) and preferably some thoughts of your own (what have you tried, where did you get stuck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the area of the image of $f$ is not helpful, because the area is infinite. The right idea is to look at the area of the *complement* of the image.

For $0<r<1$, the area bounded by the Jordan curve $f(|z|=r)$ is
$$-\frac{1}{2i} \int_{|z|=r} \overline{f(z)}f'(z)\,dz = \pi \sum_{n=-1}^\infty n|a_n|^2 r^{2n-1} $$
where I include $a_{-1}=1$ in the series.
Since this quantity expresses the area of  something, it is **nonnegative**. Let $r\to1$ and draw the desired conclusion.